# data is not inserting in database c# winform

Tags: javascript, c#

I am using vs 2013 and i am using service base database for my windows based application i am creating employee management application while inserting data it shows me Records inserted but the data is updating in the database,anyone can help me...

```
 void metroButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                con = new SqlConnection(cs.DBcon);

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_employee VALUES(@Designation, @Date, @Employee_name,@Leave,@L_Reason,@Performance,@Payment,@Petrol,@Grand_Total)", con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Designation", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Employee_name", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Leave", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@L_Reason", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Performance", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Payment", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Petrol", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Grand_Total", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value);

                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }


            }
            MessageBox.Show("Records inserted.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the error message ?

Comment: Actually what error are you getting?

Comment: You are trying to make an SQLCommand without a vaild SQL connection. Open the connection before you create the command instance.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to add a con.BeginTransaction() before the ExecuteNonQuery and a con.Commit() after the ExecuteNonQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You should open the connection before you make the command instance, like this:

```
void metroButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        con = new SqlConnection(cs.DBcon);

        con.Open(); //Open the connection

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_employee VALUES(@Designation, @Date, @Employee_name,@Leave,@L_Reason,@Performance,@Payment,@Petrol,@Grand_Total)", con)) //Now create the command
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Designation", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Employee_name", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Leave", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@L_Reason", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Performance", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Payment", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Petrol", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Grand_Total", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        con.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Records inserted.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: The same issue is occurring the data insert message is showing but data is not updating i used all suggestion but same issue happening

Comment: Are you sure you want "dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1" because that means you won't insert one row into the DB. So if you have 1 row then you won't insert anything at all into the DB. Try "for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)"

Answer (score 0):

Perform everything inside connection as below

```
    void metroButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cs.DBcon))
                    {
                      connection.Open();
                      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Designation", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
                      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
                      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Employee_name", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
                      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Leave", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
                      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@L_Reason", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
                      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Performance", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
                      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Payment", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value);
                      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Petrol", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value);
                      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Grand_Total", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value);
                      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                      connection.Close();
                  }


                }
                MessageBox.Show("Records inserted.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```